# TinyMCE5: Remove <strong> from within all h1-h6 elements

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

By default, TinyMCE allows the `h1`--`h6` elements to include a `<strong>` element, but it's problematic, since with some fonts the default strong weight of the header tags is then added by extra weight, which looks terrible.

I've tried using the `valid_children` option:

```
valid_children : '-h1[strong],-h2[strong],-h3[strong],-h4[strong],-h5[strong],-h6[strong]'
```

However, while this prevents implementing `<strong>` on `h1`--`h6`, it resolves existing cases by removing the `h1`-`h6` elements and replacing those with `p` elements:

```
<h3><strong>Subtitle goes here</strong></h3>
```

Is converted into:

```
<p><strong>Subtitle goes here</strong></p>
```

The desired behaviour, however, is:

```
<h3>Subtitle goes here</h3>
```

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add these codes:

```
  formats: {
    h1: { block : 'h1', styles: { fontSize: '40px', 'font-weight': 'normal' }},
    h2: { block : 'h2', styles: { fontSize: '32px', 'font-weight': 'normal' }},
    h3: { block : 'h3', styles: { fontSize: '28px', 'font-weight': 'normal' }},
    h4: { block : 'h4', styles: { fontSize: '24px', 'font-weight': 'normal' }},
    h5: { block : 'h5', styles: { fontSize: '20px', 'font-weight': 'normal' }},
    h6: { block : 'h6', styles: { fontSize: '16px', 'font-weight': 'normal' }},
  },
```

and it works with;

```
<h3><strong>Subtitle goes here</strong></h3>
```

It can be solve your problem.